# Deploy angular 6 universal on firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-universal

I have been following the steps but it is not working... I have created a dynamic angular 6 app and installed angular universal on it. On Localhost it is working but when I upload it to firebase, it is not... I followed everything but at one point they ask to edit the /functions/index.js folder... But in my project, there is no functions folder. So I am confused.
I am using the firebase free hosting

Comment: We need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase tools creates the functions folder during setup, you can choose either js or ts extensions for the index file along with other options as to how you want to run your app. Some additional files will also help with config of your app.

```
npm install -g firebase-tools

firebase init
```

**firebasesrc**

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "default-firebase-account-name",
    "dev": "dev--firebase-account-name",
    "prod": "poduction--firebase-account-name"
  }
}
```

project name config. Adding your firebase project name here with an alias to quickly configure different environments from your console.

```
firebase use dev
or
firebase use prod
```

**firebase.json**

Main hosting config to setup hosting, headers, database, storage and rewrite rule paths.

Database rules, storage and indexes files can be created during the firebase init procedure.

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/browser",
```

**functions/**

cd into this directory and run npm install / yarn install or choose install during init. 
 functions/package.json will be created with deployment scripts.

*note if using windows - git bash may not allow selection of options with arrow keys so use windows powershell instead for initial setup. Then either deploy via powershell with stadard*

```
firebase deploy
```

or add these to your main package.json scripts and chain them to your production build script for easy one step deployment from console.

```
"prod": "ng build --prod"
"prod:dep": "cd functions && firebase deploy",
"postprod:host": "cd functions && firebase deploy --only hosting",
```

More information can be found here re [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying) hosting